# Bootstrap Table - To open div, from a image link, of content json file

Tags: bootstrap-table

I have a table loaded using a json file in a modal window:

HTML CODE

```
<table id="table-alert3" class="table table-striped"></table>
```

JS CODE

```
$("#table-alert3").bootstrapTable({
    url: 'json/data-table-alert3.json',
    columns: [{
        field: 'col1'
    }, {
        field: 'col2'
    }, ]
});
```

JSON CONTENT:

```
[
    {
        "col1": "Juan Perez",
        "col2": "<a href='#' class='opendiv'><img src='img/ico_add_td.png' /></a>"
    },
    {
        "col1": "Sergio Montes",
        "col2": "<a href='#' class='opendiv'><img src='img/ico_add_td.png' /></a>"
    }
]
```

For each image link , when i make clic about image, i want to open a div, and your position must be relative to the image

How could do it?

Thanks,

Comment: im looking about popover bootstrap, maybe i can do it with this